# On odd perfect numbers $N$ given in the Eulerian form $N = {q^k}{n^2}$, Part II

Tags: divisibility, factoring, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

(Note:  This has been cross-posted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/202376).)

A positive integer $N$ is said to be *perfect* if $\sigma(N) = 2N$, where $\sigma(x)$ is the sum of the divisors of $x$.

An *odd perfect number* $N$ is said to be given in *Eulerian form* if $N = {q^k}{n^2}$, where $q$ is prime, $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

[Broughan, Delbourgo and Zhou (2013)](http://www.math.waikato.ac.nz/~kab/papers/chenchenformatted.pdf) defines the *perfect number index of $N$ at prime $r$* to be the integer
$$m := \frac{\sigma(N/{r^{\alpha}})}{r^{\alpha}},$$
where $r^{\alpha} || N$.  They also show that $m \ge 315$.  ([Chen and Chen (2014)](http://journals.impan.gov.pl/cm/Inf/136-1-4.html) extend these results in "On the index of an odd perfect number".)

Since $\sigma$ is weakly multiplicative, we have
$$\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)=\sigma(N)=2N=2{q^k}{n^2}.$$
Because $\gcd(q^k,\sigma(q^k))=1$, this means that
$$\sigma(n^2)/q^k = 2{n^2}/\sigma(q^k) = s \in \mathbb{N},$$
where $s \ge 315$.

In particular, we have the simultaneous equations
$$\sigma(n^2) = s{q^k}$$
and
$$2{n^2} = s{\sigma(q^k)}.$$

We obtain
$$2{n^2} - \sigma(n^2) = s{\sigma(q^k)} - s{q^k} = s{\sigma(q^{k-1})}.$$

It follows that
$$\sigma(q^{k-1}) \mid (2{n^2} - \sigma(n^2)).$$

Now, here is my question:

> What are the divisors of $\sigma(q^{k-1})$?

Notice that $4 \mid (k-1)$.

Comment: By simple congruence considerations,
$$\sigma(q^{k-1}) \equiv \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}{1} \equiv 1 + (k - 1) \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4.$$

Comment: Additionally, I checked using WolframAlpha and found only the following factorization (for $k = 9$):

$$\sigma(q^8) = 1 + q + q^2 + q^3 + q^4 + q^5 + q^6 + q^7 + q^8 = (q^2 + q + 1)(q^6 + q^3 + 1) = \sigma(q^2)(q^6 + q^3 + 1).$$